# What did George Orr have in his coffee in the novel "The Lathe of Heaven"?

Tags: the-lathe-of-heaven

In Ursula K. LeGuin's *The Lathe of Heaven*, both the paperback and the Amazon Kindle eBook fail to note what George Orr had in his coffee.

pg. 114

> He took Orr down to the food machines, and got him a roast beef sandwich, an egg and tomato sandwich, two apples, four chocolate bars, and two cups of coffee with.

I remember the next word as "everything", presumably from a library hardcover --- but the novel was originally serialized in *Amazing Stories Magazine* --- was the text there complete?

Comment: That's what the Internet Archive is four. It's just "coffee with". Just search for the word "coffee". https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v45n01_1971-05

Comment: Ending sentences with prepositions is what ELU is for.

Comment: "coffee with" just means w/ milk and sugar.

Comment: @Fattie - [Ahem](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/240800/20774)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The original publication in the [May 1973 issue of *Amazing Science Fiction*](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v45n01_1971-05/page/n25/mode/1up?q=coffee) has exactly that text.  (The link should take you to the correct page with "coffee" highlighted.)

I expect that is simply an idiomatic English usage that is somewhat archaic now.  I've heard it more often in a sentence like "I went to the store and John came with."  The missing antecedent "me" is implied by the structure of the sentence.  (There being nothing/nobody else for John to be with.)

In this case I read that sentence as "...got him a roast beef sandwich, an egg and tomato sandwich, two apples, four chocolate bars, and two cups of coffee [**to go with all that**]."

Comment: Of course in the first part of the novel they seemed to have coffee with brandy a fair bit, so if you're used to seeing that it could be even more confusing.

Comment: I've heard this a lot from UK speakers: "I'm going for a walk; want to come with?", and is how I would have interpreted the LeGuin passage before seeing Valorum's answer. In the absence of "come" or "go" I'm now thinking "coffee with" means the usual add-ins.

Comment: 'Want to come with?' is very colloquial, I would interpret it be regarding with or without milk as specified by the people above.

Comment: This answer is **simply completely wrong** and the other answer is correct.  I suggest deleting it.

Comment: @Fattie - It has value because it confirms that the original wording is correct.

Answer (score 40):

This is idiomatic (US/UK) English. He had his coffee with [milk and sugar].

> "Do you wish your tea or coffee to be with or without sugar or with or without milk? How do you like your tea? With or without? **Do you drink your coffee with or without?"**
>
> <sub><sup>[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/With+or+without%3F)</sup></sub>

The lady who owned my local greasy spoon used to ask people if they wanted *"tea with or tea without"*. If the customer wanted anything special (e.g. *two* sugars) the onus was on them to be more specific.

Comment: This answer was much helped by the fact that I've actually heard the expression used in a real setting. The slang dictionary reference is merely a flourish.

Comment: In Holland, you might buy a portion of chips/fries and be asked "with or without", where the implied word is "mayonnaise". I imagine there are a bunch of other examples in different places and contexts where something has an accompaniment so common as to be default, but not universal.

Comment: A comparative US usage might be the (Philadelphia regional) "whiz wit" or "prov witout" ("cheese whiz with onions" and "provolone, no onions", respectively) when ordering a cheesesteak.

Comment: Discussion about "down to" vs "up to", while interesting, is not directly relevant to the Q&A here and has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117651/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-what-did-george-orr-have-in-his-coffee-in-the-no).

Comment: I am not convinced that this is deliberate. I've heard this usage before, but in this particular sentence it doesn't seem natural. And it doesn't really seem to fit Ursula K. Le Guin's writing style. Personally, I think it's just an editing error, where she either meant to include or remove a whole phrase but missed part.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Agreed. I've reworded it now so that it won't provoke the same discussion.

Comment: I dislike the slang "dictionary" quote, Valo.  It's just confusing.  the quote **does not*** actually use the term "coffee with" as such.  It's just a few long sentences that start with "coffee with milk" and "lead up to" saying "Do you drink your coffee with or without"  The phrase in question is simply not used.  It's a horrible confusing reference.

Comment: @user3067860 , it completely fits the style of the character and the tone. Anyone as erudite as LeGuin would have of course known such an everyday-ism of the time.  (Just as for example today, locally in NYC, "regular" has a specific, widely used (by 10+m people) known meaning: https://gothamist.com/food/why-a-regular-coffee-means-coffee-with-cream-and-sugar )

Comment: @Fattie I don't see any evidence that "coffee with" was ever a set phrase (and I've consumed a decent amount of media from the 70s). "With _or without_" in the context of coffee, yes. "One lump or two", yes. But "coffee with." just means someone stopped in the middle of the sentence. Even if a character would use that as slang, it doesn't appear to be in dialog or in first person. It looks like a third person narrator. In the other quotes that I can find from that book, the third person narrator is written with "correct" grammar, no slang.

Comment: @user3067860 - If you cast your eyes upwards, you'll find examples listed in my answer. So now you have seen evidence.

Comment: @Valorum I *don't* see examples listed in your answer. I only see examples for "with _or without_".

Comment: @user3067860 , cheers, *"I don't see any evidence that "coffee with" was ever a set phrase"* - this is an ongoing epistemological problem on this site. All of one category of questions are really about "Is XYZ a common phrase amongst English speakers?" (Perhaps in a given region / time period.)  {Note that there are *no or usually none references for spoken English*.}  It's perfectly common on the site that A will say "xyz is a common phrase, everyone knows that", whereas B will then say "You're nuts, never heard of it."  In this case I am A and you are B....

Comment: Note that *even when* say *a magazine or newspaper article* is supplied, that, happens to mention the phrase in question being used in speech (for example, notice my article about a "regular") it's *still* totally common that B and or C will reply saying "that article is stupid, it's not a term at all". Indeed, i am very often B (or C)  :)  Unfortunately (as every time on this site) it's just an impasse.  {Note that if you want an example of usage in this case, even in print, even from a leading novelist - there's one quoted in the question :) }